# Remove the space between div rows

Tags: html, css, grid, rows

I try to remove the extra space between this div rows of content (I would like to have just 1 row of space netween them):

http://www.startupexpats.com/marketplace/

this is my css:

```
.content {
          -moz-column-count: 3;
          -moz-column-gap: 5px;
          -moz-column-rule: none;
          -webkit-column-count: 3;
          -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
          -webkit-column-rule: none;
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 5px;
        column-rule: none;
        }
```

what im doing wrong?